# passport js fails to maintain session when nodejs server restarts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am using  `nodejs, passportjs, jwtoken and mongoose` to develop an application. I am facing some critical situation and stuck since 2 days.

I have used `passport js` for server side authentication and `jwtoken` for persistent login. It works very well ,with regular situation. But I have faced an issue before 3 days ago that when I restart server passport js fails to maintain session or expire nodejs user session. I don't know how to revalidate and recreate new passport session in nodejs.

I have tried a lot but failed to recreate. I found this issue when I tried to restart server and from web application any request sent to server. When I tried to access req.user to get user data from session it throws me req.user is undefined.

I even tried to use `connect-mongo` to store session but it throws an error -

`"Error: failed to deserialize user out of session"`.

I don't know how to deal with situation. Provide me guidelines to resolve this issue.

Please refer below source code.

> config.js

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var expressSession = require("express-session");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var morgan = require("morgan");
var passport = require("passport");
var randToken = require('rand-token');
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var app = express();

var useragent = require('express-useragent');
app.use(useragent.express());

require("./utils")(express, app, path);

require("./db");

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 2000);
app.set("env", "development");

if (app.get("env") === 'production') {
    process.env['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['COOKIE_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['JWT_TIME_OUT'] = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000; // 30 days
    process.env['SECURE_COOKIES'] = true;
} else if (app.get('env') === 'staging') {
    process.env['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['COOKIE_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['JWT_TIME_OUT'] = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000; // 30 days
    process.env['SECURE_COOKIES'] = false;
} else if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    process.env['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['COOKIE_PRIVATE_KEY'] = **** ;
    process.env['JWT_TIME_OUT'] = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000; // 30 days
    process.env['SECURE_COOKIES'] = false;
}

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(expressSession({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    name: 'hz-app',
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    httponly: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

var router = express.Router();
var expressJWT = require("express-jwt");
var allowAccess = expressJWT({
    secret: process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY,
    userProperty: 'payload'
}).unless({
    path: [
        '/api/user/register',
        '/api/user/useractivation',
        '/api/user/authenticate',
        '/api/user/checkEmail',
        '/api/user/checkNickName',
        '/api/user/resetPassword',
        '/api/user/addip',
        '/api/user/forgetPasswordRequest',
        '/api/user/logout',
        '/api/cms/getCms',
        '/adminapi/admin/authnticate',
        '/adminapi/admin/logout',
        '/adminapi/common/getLanguageList',
        '/api/common/getCurrencyList',
        '/adminapi/common/getUserType',
        '/api/newsSubscriber/create',
        //        '/api/newsSubcrib/create',
        //        '/adminapi/admin/userList',
        //        '/adminapi/admin/getUserType',
        //        '/adminapi/admin/userCreate',
        //        '/adminapi/admin/userEdit',

    ]
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.all(["/api/*", "/adminapi/*"], allowAccess, function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        console.log("log in authorize obj for check");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.user));
    } else {
        console.log("not authenticated (not log in)");
        //res.clearCookie('hz-token');
        //res.clearCookie('hz-token-admin');
    }

    var reqPath = req.path.split("/");
    console.log('../app/data/routes/' + reqPath[2]);
    app.use(require('../app/data/routes/' + reqPath[2]));
    next();
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    //app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(basePath + "app/client/views/index.html");
});

app.get("/admin", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(basePath + "app/admin/views/index.html");
});

//Development error handler will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === "development") {
    router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Epsilon is listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
exports = module.exports = app;
```

> user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Helper = require("../components/helper");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
var moment = require("moment");
var User = require('../models/user');
var passport = require("passport");
var localStrategy = require("passport-local"),
        Startegy;

router
        .route('/api/user/authenticate')
        .post(
                function (req, res, next) {
                    console.log(">> authentication process initiated");

                    passport.authenticate('user-local', function (err, user, info) {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(401).json({
                                status: 0,
                                code: 401,
                                type: "error",
                                message: err
                            });
                        }
                        if (!user) {
                            console.log("not user:");
                            console.log(user);
                            return res.status(401).json({
                                status: 0,
                                code: 401,
                                type: "error",
                                message: info
                            });
                        }
                        req.login(user, {}, function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                return res.status(500).json({
                                    status: 0,
                                    code: 500,
                                    type: "other",
                                    err: 'could not login user'
                                });
                            }

                            NextProcessForGenerateWebToken();

                            var NextProcessForGenerateWebToken = function () {
                                if (err) {
                                    return next(err);
                                }
                                var _res = user.generateJWT(user);
                                res.cookie('hz-token', _res, {maxAge: process.env.JWT_TIME_OUT, httpOnly: false});
                                res.status(200).json({
                                    status: 1,
                                    type: "success",
                                    message: 'login successful',
                                    res: {
                                        link: user.link_id,
                                        nick_name: user.nick_name
                                    }
                                });
                            };
                        });
                    })(req, res, next);
                });


/**
 * Serialize user for passport authentication
 */
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log("serialize:>>"+user.id);
    console.log(user);
    done(null, user.id);
});

/**
 * Deserialize user for passport authentication
 */
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        console.log("deserialize:>>"+user.id);
        done(err, user);
    });
});

/**
 * Passport local authentication policy to validate email/username and passport
 */
passport.use('user-local', new localStrategy({
    usernameField: 'txtSigninEmail',
    passwordField: 'txtSigninPassword'
},
        function (username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({$or: [{email: username}, {nick_name: new RegExp('^' + username + '$', "i")}], user_type: 3, is_active: 1, is_close: 0}, function (err, user) {
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username.'});
                }

                user.comparePassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    if (!isMatch) {
                        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password.'});
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            });
        }
));

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Start by providing some code. It sounds like your `passport.serializeUser()/passport.deserializeUser()` functions may be problematic, combined with using a non-persistent session store.

Comment: @robertklep: I have attached source code of config.js and user.js which is primarily responsible for authentication.

Comment: It looks like your session store is not persistent (it's only keeping the sessions in memory, not in a database of some sorts), which explains why the sessions are gone after a restart. The issue could also be that older sessions were causing problems when you added `connect-mongo` into the mix (I think that _"failed to deserialize user out of session"_ is not a real problem; if the user is allowed to log in when it happens, it's basically just a warning, and since you changed session stores, it's even to be expected).

Comment: @robertklep: Is there possible that we can use only json web token only the for validation of authenticated request. In each request we validate only JWToken and token passed through signed cookies from server. So, it doesn't require to store any session in server and our issue may resolve. can you guide on our idea?

Comment: @robertklep: so we don't require any database it verifies real-time in each request. if requested token is not authenticated, denied to access an application area. Is it good idea to use only jwtoken?

Comment: I've never combined Passport with JWT's before, so can't help you with that. There _is_ a specific Passport strategy to deal with JWT's, [`passport-jwt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt), perhaps that's useful.

Comment: @robertklep: ok thank you to give your useful suggestions.